# zsh: no matches found: [:space:]

Tags: whitespace, zsh, removing-whitespace, oh-my-zsh, tr

For some reason, in zsh, I'm unable to use the [:space:] pattern to match all whitespace.

ex.

```
$ echo 'Welcome To Here' | tr [:space:] '\t'
zsh: no matches found: [:space:]
```

But if I do this in bash, then it works fine

```
$ echo 'Welcome To Here' | tr [:space:] '\t'
Welcome To  Here
```

Would this be some kind of problem in my ~/.zshrc, or does zsh not support this? I'm also using oh my zsh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`zsh` sees the `[:space:]` and interpets it as a wildcard glob that will match a file named `:`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `c` or `e`. When there are no such files, it produces an error. So will `bash` with the `failglob` shell option enabled - your setup presumably turns it off somewhere. Just wrap it in quotes to prevent expansion:

```
echo 'Welcome To Here' | tr '[:space:]' '\t'
```